# Webhost that allows outbound connections...?

Tags: language-agnostic, web-hosting

Does anyone know of a host that would allow this kind of code to run (any language):

```
socket.open(
    "69.128.34.54", //any ip address basically
    5555); // also any port
//write to socket...
//get response...
socket.close();
```

I am looking for pretty much any outbound IP, and pretty much any standard port (1024-65535). Note: these are for outbound only, no incoming other than ofc your standard port 80.

Answer (score 1):

For your standard shared hosting:

Ugh, I doubt you'll find one that openly allows that, seeing it's wide open, and from a security point of view, dangerous.

However, is there any way you can limit the ports (UDP/TCP) to a smaller range? Doing so would alleviate the stress a web host will feel when they get this request.

For semi dedicated / private / dedicated hosts
If you're willing to pump out the dough, I believe WebHost4Life might, Arvixe might, but you'd have to trim down the ports.

Again, spreading a firewalls outgoing ports wide open is bad for a web server.

Comment: I see.... Hm perhaps a VPS would allow this? I could live with running a webservice that is connected somewhere that this is allowed.